# Problema de encoding no Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres, unicode

Em certo momento do meu código eu recebo uma váriavel `var` do tipo str contendo `SENTEN\u00c7A`.

ao fazer

```
var2 = var.encode()
print(var2)
```

é printado `b'SENTEN\\u00c7A'`

A palavra original seria 'SENTENÇA'

Ao fazer `print('SENTENÇA'.encode())` me retorna `b'SENTEN\xc3\x87A'`

Ao fazer `print(var == 'SENTENÇA')` me retorna `false`

Como posso fazer a conversão da minha variável `var` para que seja igual a 'SENTENÇA'? Essa variável vem de outro programa, pode vir outra palavra também, como faço essa conversão genérica?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Resumindo:

Sua string foi "escapada duas vezes". Ela tem que ser lida como se fosse bytes, e a partir daí, decodificada com o codec "unicode_escape". Basta fazer:

```
var2 = var.encode("latin1").decode("unicode_escape")
```

## Explicação

A sua string original `var` em algum ponto passou por um processo de "codificação dupla" - nesse processo, o caractere unicode "Ç" - que  tem o código 124 (0xC7 em hexadecimal) "\u007c" teve essa sequência "transplantada" para dentro da string. Normalmente essa representação - "\u00c7" é usada apenas como uma forma de mostrar caracteres mais complicados quando se vê a forma "repr" da string, ou então, para se colocar caracteres especiais diretamente através de seu código na string literal. A pista para entender que isso aconteceu é que quando você imprime o valor em bytes da string, pode-se notar que a barra "\" foi impressa de forma duplicada. O Python faz isso para indicar a presença de um caratére "físico" de \, e que a barra não está só sendo usada como marcador para modificar o próximo caracter da sequência impressa

Por exemplo `rei_preto = "\u265a"` é o caractere para um rei preto do xadrez. 
No entanto, ao se fazer isso de forma normal o conteúdo da string vai ser somente aquele caractere especial, não a sequência de 6 caracteres "\u265a" - veja no prompt do ipython:

```
In [107]: rei = "\u265a"                                                                                 

In [108]: print(rei)                                                                                     
♚

In [109]: len(rei)                                                                                       
Out[109]: 1
```

Então, como eu expliquei acima, alguma coisa no seu processo aplicou duas vezes o procedimento de "unicode_escape" ao seu texto antes de chegar na variável "var".
O remédio para isso é transformar de forma transparente o seu texto para um conjunto de bytes - ou seja - cada caractér da string "SENTEN\u00C7A" é passada sem nenhuma transformação para um uma string de bytes do Python 3. Isso é feito com o codec "latin1" - todos os códigos de 0 a 255 tem uma corrêspondencia de 1 pra 1 entre sua representação em texto, e sua representação no charset Latin-1 (isso inclui toda a tabela ASCII e mais os caracteres acentuados mais comuns - os usados em português inclusive). O segundo passo é *descodificar* essa sequência de bytes usando o codec especial "unicode_escape" - esse codec acha as ocorrências das marcaçóes do tipo `\xFF`, `\uAAAA` (e outras)  usadas pelo Python, e as traduz para o caractere correspondente.

Ou seja:

```
In [128]: b = "SENTEN\\u00c7A"                                                                           

In [129]: c = b.encode("latin1")                                                                         

In [130]: c.decode("unicode_escape")                                                                     
Out[130]: 'SENTENÇA'
```

**Atualização** 
Enquanto eu estava respondendo você atualizou a pergunta e descreveu como está lendo esses dados, com a linha:

```
arquivo = json.loads(sys.argv[2].replace("\\", '\\\\'))
```

Como você pode ver, isso causa o erro - ao trocar uma "\" na string de entrada por duas, faz com que duas barras passem a existir - o que  o Python interpreta como sendo uma "barra física" e não um "indicador de escape". Se você simplesmente tirar esse replace daí, provavelmente o trecho de código vai funcionar.

A forma que você está usando para passar dados para o script Python no entanto não é de forma alguma confiável -  e você deveria usar outro mecanismo para isso. Você está passando um objeto com notação JSON pelo SHELL - e o shel lusa TODOS os caracteres delimitadores de JSON  `[, {, "` (além do próprio espaço em branco), de forma especial. A chance de dar algo errado é de cerca de 300% (como já deu). Uma pessoa com sólidos conhecimentos em Shell e escaping poderia escrever código que fizesse isso - eu me considero uma pessoa com sólidos conhecimentos em Unicode, mas as transformações que o Shell faz com esses caracteres estão além do meu alcance.

O melhor é você gravar seus dados num arquivo temporário de dentro do PHP e passar apenas o nome do arquivo para o script Python - e então  "json.load" pode ler o arquivo inteiro de uma vez.

Uma arquitetura melhor talvez fosse usar um servidor "[redis](https://redis.io/)" local - você insere seus dados lá a partir do PHP, e lê do redis no processo em Python: isso permitiria que o que quer que você esteja fazendo em Python seja executado como um serviço continuo, e não com um novo processo, iniciado via shell, a cada page-view (que tipicamente é quando o PHP vai precisar dos serviços do Python).

Comment: A strign está certa como eu coloquei - se está imprimindo assim, é por que o Python está codificandom no momento da impressão para "utf-8", mas o seu terminal está em Latin1. (a dica nesse caso: quando um programa tenta interpretar uma string de bytes que está  em utf-8  como se fosse Latin-1, aparece sempre o caractere "Ã" seguido de algum outro caractere acentuado ou não imprimível). Se está lendo direto a saída do Python para o PHP, em vez de imprimindo no terminal então a saída da sua página do PHP não está colocando cabeçalhos de acentuação, e por padrão, dos 1990, o codec é latin1.

Comment: ... coloque o seu programa php para incluir o cabeçalho http `Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8` na página gerada para poder ver os caracteres utf-8 gerados pelo Python na página gerada.